# Django build a blog, connect database failed

Tags: python, django, macos, django-models

I'm a python and Django learner. I followed the tutorial
(http://www.creativebloq.com/netmag/get-started-django-7132932) with my mac
and got some problems.

```
xinliu-mac:netmag xinliu$ python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7c1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7c1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7c1-py2.7.egg/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7c1-py2.7.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 106, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7c1-py2.7.egg/django/apps/config.py", line 190, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/xinliu/djcode/netmag/blog/models.py", line 16
    return u'&s % self.title
                           ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

My database of `settings.py` is:

```
 60 DATABASES = {
 61     'default': {
 62         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
 63         'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'netmag.db'),
 64     }
 65 }
```

and the path is:

```
 12 import os
 13 BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

So what's wrong?

Comment: Look at the error message. It points to line 16 of `blog/models.py`.

Comment: There's a `'` missing.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in:

```
  File "/Users/xinliu/djcode/netmag/blog/models.py", line 16
       return u'&s % self.title
```

There are two errors.

1. There is a line missing it should be: `return '&s' % self.title`
2. And second is `%` not `&` so it must be: `return '%s' % self.title`